# pl/sql function showing syntax error

Tags: plsql

I am new in pl/sql. i have write a pl/sql function using sql developer with proper 
package name & body.

I function is showing this error:

image given below:

[image]

Here is the pl/sql code:

```
  create or replace PACKAGE  PAYROLL AS
            FUNCTION save_payroll_transaction(transaction_data NVARCHAR2 ) RETURN nclob;
END PAYROLL;
```

Body:

```
 create or replace PACKAGE BODY PAYROLL IS 
       FUNCTION save_payroll_transaction(transaction_data NVARCHAR2 ) RETURN nclob IS ret nclob;
       xmlData XMLType;
       BEGIN 
       xmlData:=XMLType(transaction_data);
       INSERT INTO PAYROLLFILE SELECT x.* FROM XMLTABLE('/transaction'
                                                    PASSING xmlData
                                                    COLUMNS "salary_year"       NUMBER(4,0)     PATH  "SALYR",
                                                            "salary_month"      NUMBER(2,0)     PATH  "SALMT",
                                                            "employee_id"       NUMBER            PATH  "EMPID",
                                                            "department_code" NUMBER        PATH  "DPTID",
                                                            "salary_head"       VARCHAR2(2)     PATH  "SALHD",
                                                            "description"       VARCHAR2(50)    PATH  "DESCR",
                                                            "amount"                FLOAT(126)      PATH  "ALAMT",
                                                            "operator_id"       NUMBER        PATH  "OPID",
                                                            "transaction_date" DATE           PATH  "TRADT") x;


         ret:=to_char(sql%rowcount);
    COMMIT;

    RETURN '<result><status affectedRow='||ret||'>success</status></result>';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN '<result><status>Error</status></result>';

    END save_payroll_transaction;

    END PAYROLL;
```

please help.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML path is a string, not an identifier, so you need to enclose it in single quotes:

```
"salary_year"       NUMBER(4,0)     PATH  'SALYR'  -- not "SALYR"
```

Comment: Thanks @Kombajn zbożowy